# MPI_File_write_all with different count value for each processor

Tags: c++, mpi, mpi-io

This is maybe a dumb question but,

I would like that `N` processors write all a different `byte count` in the same file with a different `offset` to make the data contignously.

I would like to use `MPI_File_write_all(file,data,count,type,status)` (individual file pointers, collective, blocking) function.

The first question can each processor specify a different value for the `count` parameter? 
I could not find anything mentioned in the MPI 3.0 reference. (My intention is that it is not possible?)

What I found out so far is the following two problems:

1. When I want to write a large amount of `MPI_BYTES` the integer (32bit) `count` in the MPI_File_write... functions is to little and gives overflow of course!
2. I do not (cannot)/want to use a derived data type in MPI because as mentioned above all processor write a different `byte count` and the type is `MPI_BYTES`

Thanks for any help on this topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've rolled up a few questions here

- Absolutely, proceses can specify different or even zero amounts of data to the collective `MPI_File_write_all` routine.   Not only can the `count` parameter differ, there's no reason the `datatype` parameter needs to be the same either.
- Problem #1: If you want to write more than an `int` worth of MPI_BYTE data, you'll have to create a new datatpye.  For example, let's say you wanted to write 9 billion bytes.  Create a contig type of size 1 billion, then write 9 of those.  (if the amount of data you want to write is not evenly divisible, you might need an hindexed or struct type).
- problem #2: It's not at all a problem to have every MPI process create its own datatype or count of datatype.