# Can I use MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL when some processors do not write any data?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I am modifying a colleague's subroutine to write a subset of 3D Cartesian data to a single binary file. The data comes from high fidelity fluid simulations that span multiple processors written in Fortran90. The goal is to export slices or smaller contiguous 3D subsets for visualization purposes. In general, not all processors will intersect the specified slice. Can I use `MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL` even though some processors write zero data? or do I have to use only non-collective subroutines?

The previous version of the subroutine which dumps the entire 3D data relies on the subroutines `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY`, `MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW`, `MPI_TYPE_COMMIT`, and `MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL`. I'm a little unclear on which of these are collective and which may need to be replaced with local routines.

I am newer to MPI so I apologize if this is a bit basic. Directions to reliable documentation is also appreciated in lieu of specific advice.

EDIT: After banging my head against this for a while, I may at least have an alternate framing for the question that will hopefully make it more focused and approachable.

I want this section of the code to function effectively like this:

```
! Relevant variables and their types
real(WP), pointer :: r1_data(:)
integer           :: ierr, r1_type, fh, offset
integer           :: sizes(3), subsizes(3), starts(3), status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
integer           :: my_data_count, data_count

integer :: i_start, j_start, k_start
integer :: i_end, j_end, k_end
integer :: index
real(WP), allocatable :: my_data(:,:,:)

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
! Initialization code, including correctly  
! populating 'starts', 'sizes', 'subsizes' and
! offset takes place here.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(3, sizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN,MPI_REAL_WP,r1_type,ierr)   
call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(r1_type, ierr)

!-- populate the data buffer
index = 0
do k=k_start,k_end
  do j=j_start,j_end
    do i=i_start,i_end
      index = index + 1
      r1_data(index) = my_data(i,j,k)
    enddo
  enddo
enddo

call MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW(fh,offset,MPI_REAL_WP,r1_type,'native',MPI_INFO_NULL,ierr)
call MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL(fh,r1_data,my_data_count,MPI_REAL_WP,status,ierr)
```

This works fine if all processors have a portion of the subarray to write, but the problem arises when the local portion of the subarray has a size of zero (one or more entries of `subsizes` is zero) is zero for a processor, in which case `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY` cannot be called and `r1_type` is not assigned.

It would be ideal if I could continue to use 'collective write' operations for efficiency, but it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MPI\_File\_write\_all with different count value for each processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681860/mpi-file-write-all-with-different-count-value-for-each-processor)

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks! Though a little more explanation of 'how' would make it complete. My impression (I'm not confident this is true) is that each processor must call ```MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY``` and ```MPI_TYPE_COMMIT``` before writing to the file, however the processors with no data seem to be failing in the ```MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY``` call.

Comment: All ranks of the communicator must invoke the collective subroutine. Some ranks might write zero bytes though.

Comment: "seem to be failing" Is there an error message?

Comment: I've made some progress on this. It seems that MPI does not allow processors to invoke ```MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY``` if it has less than 1 element to write to the subarray, however ```MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL``` still requires a MPI Type from each processor (e.g. the subarray). Somehow I need to specify that a processor has zero bytes to write.

Comment: What do you mean by "It seems that MPI does not allow processors to invoke MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY if it has less than 1 element to write to the subarray,"? Could you edit the question to explain, including any error messages?

Comment: @IanBush Just edited. Hopefully the question is a bit more focused and tangible now. The subsizes array argument of MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY cannot have any zero elements. This is a problem here because not all of my processors will actually intersect my desired subarray. The ```MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW``` subroutine is collective and requires ```r1_type``` which is an output of ```MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY```

Comment: use any datatype but `MPI_DATATYPE_NULL` and `count=0` when there is no data to write.

Comment: Thanks @GillesGouaillardet! This appears to work, or at the very least allow the routines to be called without crashing. I will do my best to confirm this as soon as I am able.